# Azure CosmosDB indexes collection named "undefined"

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I'm following the instructions in this link https://anthonychu.ca/post/cosmos-db-mongoose-discriminators/ to store multiple document types in a single collection within an Azure Cosmos DB (Mongo API).

I'm using mongoose 5.2.10, nodejs 8.12

I do have models with fields set at "unique: true". E.g.

Here is my Base schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const baseOptions = {
    discriminatorKey: '__type',
    collection: 'data'
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Base', new mongoose.Schema({}, baseOptions))
```

And here's one of the actual models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const Base = require('./_Base')
const roles = require('../lib/auth').roles

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    displayName: { type : String, default: '' },
    email: { type : String, unique : true, required: true },
    role: { type : String , default: roles.Users },
    tenant: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Tenant'
    }
})

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)

module.exports = Base.discriminator('User', UserSchema)
```

All my data gets stored in a collection with the name 'data' as indicated in my Base model, but somehow another collection gets created in Cosmos DB named "undefine" which seems to be related to the indexes of my data collection:

[image]

Question: How to prevent the creation of this "undefined" collection and get any index-related data to be placed in the same collection as my data?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a full repro on GitHub or a Gist or something? That's a weird behavior and it'd be great to just debug it to see what might be happening.

Comment: this is a company project, can't share it.. but the code I've put here is exactly the code under my Base.js file and User.js file. I use the mongoose.connect() function without any weird option other than the URL. To query my db, I just use the standard methods such as  User.find() , etc.

Comment: mm... I think this "undefined" collection is the god ol' "system.indexes" ...

Comment: im having the same problem, just migrated a project to cosmos db and forced to use discriminator, im having this collection created too...